# Gocloak: Restropect token API fails with 400 Bad request

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am trying to use the RestropectToken in client.go in gocloak v13@v13.8.0. I have created an access token and now using that am trying to call the RestropectToken().

In client.go, if I change from "token_type_hint": "requesting_party_token" to "token_type_hint": "access_token", the API succeeds and it is all good. Am wondering, why the default option fails. Do I have to use any settings on my Client configured on Keycloak?

```
==============================================================================
~~~ REQUEST ~~~
POST  /auth/realms/Customer1/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect  HTTP/1.1
HOST   : localhost:8080
HEADERS:
        Authorization: Basic Y3VzdG9tZXIxLXNlcnZpY2UtY2xpZW50OmQ4MjkyNzRmLWQ4YTQtNGE5My1iMDM5LTk1MWE5OGM4MjQ3ZA==
        Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        User-Agent: go-resty/2.7.0 (https://github.com/go-resty/resty)
BODY   :
token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ0c2k1RGVxaE8wdFEwTktwMm0xQmplMmV4djJteVl2WmlQZVBKYnJEUWprIn0.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.1xD56SDXGx9XY07JKFl4AzleRWnQPy-AMh_DTB7LVGuIkUDt8pdfauCm5u1QPX2Vz9ou0TqOLBdLiPVd2eFbjw9iUewADB9PzZaAbZQXBPDnWLli2jkRl3yn7g4A9nhboAKR2M9I2pxstqzylnsDwrQrNViFb3qms1-DoaBl2AnjALorYJyBLSw7LfBGZea4x4gk0ssFL8jMjUoM8vB0x2cRujChGQim08qQij0yJtakUMeJaDapQYdyEW5RPDmhaZat03j25ZHxEW4DT92DL8Of14a2ZP-drpGLXxa_dgl3YLRM-TayXtxTqsFNCn3_-lveNGxa32E3kQFcYdrmTA&token_type_hint=requesting_party_token
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~~~ RESPONSE ~~~
STATUS       : 400 Bad Request
PROTO        : HTTP/1.1
RECEIVED AT  : 2023-09-29T14:59:41.534280153+05:30
TIME DURATION: 3.080334ms
HEADERS      :
        Connection: keep-alive
        Content-Length: 77
        Content-Type: application/json
        Date: Fri, 29 Sep 2023 09:29:41 GMT
BODY         :
{
   "error": "invalid_request",
   "error_description": "Failed to introspect token."
}
==============================================================================
2023/09/29 14:59:41 Retrospect error  unable to retrospect token: 400 Bad Request: invalid_request: Failed to introspect token.
```

Thanks,
/M

Comment: Looks like my keycloak was a very old version. Just updated to 21.1.1 and I see RetrospectToken() works fine even with default version.